# Mvc unit testing for newbies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Can somebody give a link to any podcasts or blogs, which can help in understanding of mvc projects unit testing? 
I'm new both to mvc and UT.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal of unit testing is to isolate each part of the program and show that the individual parts are correct. A unit test provides a strict, written contract that the piece of code must satisfy. As a result, it affords several benefits ( from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing))

- **Finds problems early :**
  Unit testing finds problems early in the development cycle.
- **Facilitates change :**
  Unit testing allows the programmer to refactor code or upgrade system
  libraries at a later date
- **Simplifies integration :**
  Unit testing may reduce uncertainty in the units themselves and can be used  in a bottom-up testing style approach
- **Documentation** :
  Unit testing provides a sort of living documentation of the system
- **Design** :
  When software is developed using a test-driven approach, the combination of
  writing the unit test to specify the interface plus the refactoring   activities performed after the test is passing, may take the place of formal 
  design. Each unit test can be seen as a design element specifying classes, 
  methods, and observable behaviour

  You can find [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/763928/MVC-Unit-Testing-Unleashed) an example how to use unit test in Asp Net MVC